# Get Unique data from excel by button click?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am new to excel macros. need some help from you.I have a excel file with 2 sheets.
in sheet one i have some data
[image]

In second sheet i need a button which will fetch the distinct C column(Mname) and their ID.
[image]

Comment: you could record yourself auto-filling a vlookup

Comment: @Stepan1010 Can i write a macro for it...Any help? i am new to it.

Comment: You can write one or you can record it - either way - whichever is easier. Something as simple as this certainly doesn't require a handwritten macro. I'll assume you know how to attach a macro to a button.

Comment: You wouldn't even need to write the macro. Stepan is suggesting you use the macro recording feature in Excel. If that feature is new to you, see if this helps: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-macro-HP010342374.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Like most Excel problems, this can be done with a macro, but could also be done with just formulas. Macros are often more trouble than they're worth, so here's the formula option. There are some interesting downsides to using formulas in this way, mainly that if you do too much in a single workbook, calculation will be very slow. But as long as you're dealing with less than a few thousand rows, it shouldn't be a problem.

---

On your primary worksheet, enter this formula in `D2`, and then drag it to auto-fill down however many rows you forsee using. When you're done, you can hide column D, if it suits you.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C:$C,$C2)<2,MAX($D$1:$D1)+1,0)
```

The `COUNTIF` formula looks for how many elements in column C match the contents of `$C2` (where `$C2` is a (partially) relative reference, so the row number will change when you auto-fill into other rows). If the count is less than 2 (the element in `$C2` is unique), then the `IF` formula returns an index number: `1` for the first unique element in the column, `2` for the second, so on. All cells in column D where the corresponding cell in C is not unique are filled with `0`.

On your second sheet, you will fill columns A and B with 'lookup' formulas, searching for positive values in column D of the primary sheet. Most people use `VLOOKUP()` for lookups, I prefer a [combination of `INDEX()` and `MATCH()`](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/). And here's a great example of why, since our 'unique index' is not in the first column of the primary sheet (so VLOOKUP wouldn't work!).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Primary Sheet'!$A:$A,MATCH(ROW(A2)-1,'Primary Sheet'!$D:$D,0)),"")
```

and for the 'Mname' column of the second sheet,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Primary Sheet'!$C:$C,MATCH(ROW(B2)-1,'Primary Sheet'!$D:$D,0)),"")
```

These lookup formulas are based on their own row number. So the formula in cell `A2` is looking for the row in column D of `Primary Sheet` that contains the unique index 2-1=`1`. The formula in `A3` looks for the index 3-1=`2`, etc. The `IFERROR()` formula that is wrapped around the lookup formula ensures that if the sought-after index is not found, the formula returns an empty string (`""`), which looks like a blank cell. This way you can prepare a large number of rows on your secondary sheet with these lookup formulas. And if there are only a small number of unique Mnames on `Primary Sheet`, your secondary sheet won't have columns full of `#N/A` errors.